# Linq Subselect with dynamic where condition

Tags: c#, linq, predicatebuilder

I am building a dynamic linq statement with predicate builder and a subselect.

Example:

```cs
Expression<Func<Table1, bool>> whereExprTbl1 = PredicateBuilder.True<Table1>();
whereExprTbl1 = whereExprTbl1.And(x => x.Field1 == 2 && tbl2.Where(y => y.Field3 == x.Field2).Count() > 0);
```

This works fine.
Now I want to do the where condition for the subselect also dynamic.

```cs
Expression<Func<Table2, bool>> whereExprTbl2 = PredicateBuilder.True<Table2>();
whereExprTbl2 = whereExprTbl2.And(y => y.Field3 == x.Field2);            
Expression<Func<Table1, bool>> whereExprTbl1 = PredicateBuilder.True<Table1>();
whereExprTbl1 = whereExprTbl1.And(x => x.Field1 == 2 
                                  && tbl2.Where(whereExprTbl2).Count() > 0);
```

This does not work because x is unknown. Any other ideas how to do this?

Comment: add one more parameter to `Func`

Comment: and this `tbl2.Where(y => y.Field3 == x.Field2).Count()` can be transform into `tbl2.Count(y => y.Field3 == x.Field2)`

Comment: You don't have to combine the predicates. You can use them in separate `Where` clauses in any LINQ query containing Table1 and Table2.